# Run a command every week with Cron?

Tags: cron, crontab

Simple question- what would a crontab entry look like for a command I want to run every week on Saturday at 8:05 AM?

Answer (score 98):

That should do it:

```
5 8 * * 6 <user> <command>
```

or for readability

```
5 8 * * Sat <user> <command>
```

documentation (`man 5 crontab`):

```
              field          allowed values
              -----          --------------
              minute         0-59
              hour           0-23
              day of month   1-31
              month          1-12 (or names, see below)
              day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Answer (score 22):

Sat 8:05AM run find

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    5       8          *             *                Sat              /usr/bin/find
```

Answer (score 12):

These answers are all correct, if you are unaware of how to use cron in the future, use one of many [cron generators](https://www.google.at/search?q=cron+generators):

- http://www.cronmaker.com/
- http://www.crontab-generator.org/

Answer (score 2):

From extensive investigation of "man 5 crontab", it looks like this'll do the trick:

5 8 * * sat /usr/bin/man 5 crontab

Answer (score 1):

```
5     8     *     *     6         *your command*
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html

5 8 * * 6 /usr/bin/foo

...to run every week on Saturday at 8:05 AM

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

Change crontab:

```
5 8    * * *   <user>   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
```

And put all your command scripts in this directory /etc/cron.daily. Make sure that you have added the execution rights for them.